# How to make a toggle switch with embedded text?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a toggle switch that has embedded text within it. A toggle between monthly and annually pricing.

Here is a picture of the mock:

[image: Mock-toggle-image]

The website is built in React. I tried using [React-Toggle Pkg](https://gfazioli.github.io/react-toggle/components/toggle)

I can get the styling perfectly with this package, but I cannot figure out a good way to get text within the toggle.

```
<Toggle
  name="t-6"
  radius="50px"
  radiusBackground="50px"
  knobRadius="50px"
  width="400px"
  height="55px"
  knobWidth="200px"
  knobHeight="40px"
  onToggle={(e) => console.log("onToggle", e.target)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its not implemented, looking through the docs it doesn't look like it.

Dont despair, with a little bit of DOM (less lines then including the component) and CSS, you can achieve this with a couple of radio inputs and accompanying labels.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="pricing"]').forEach(input =>
  input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = `Value: ${this.value}`
  })
)

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = `Value: monthly`
```

```css
.pricing-toggle {
  background-color: #3FAED7;
  padding: 14px 5px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block
}

.pricing-toggle [name="pricing"] {
  display: none
}

.pricing-toggle input[type="radio"]+label {
  background-color: #3FAED7;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.pricing-toggle input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: white;
  color: #00008B;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-toggle">
  <input type="radio" id="pricing-toggle-monthly" name="pricing" value="monthly" checked>
  <label class="radio-button" for="pricing-toggle-monthly"> Monthly</label>

  <input type="radio" id="pricing-toggle-annually" name="pricing" value="annually">
  <label class="radio-button" for="pricing-toggle-annually"> Annually</label>
</div>

<div id="out"><div>
```

js in the example is not needed and with scss the CSS could be much smaller